# MVC 3 Passing null from View to Controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Whenever I try to pass a value from the view to the controller using a model, it shows up in the controller as null.  I tried something very similar in another part of the project and did not have this problem.  Why is this coming back null?

Here is the code from the controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MovieProject2.Models;

namespace MovieProject2.Controllers
{

public class ReviewsController : Controller
{
public ActionResult Edit(int id = -1)
{
    if (id < 0)
    return HttpNotFound();
    MovieReview review = MovieADO.getReviewByID(id);
    return View(review);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(MovieReview review)
{
    if (review == null) return HttpNotFound();
    return View(review);
}
}
```

View:

```
@model MovieProject2.Models.MovieReview

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit Review";
}

@{  //Not null here
    if(@Model != null) {<h2>Edit Review for @Model.MovieReviewed.Title</h2>
    <h4>Reviewed by @Model.Reviewer.Username</h4>}
                                                 else{<h2>Not Found</h2>
}
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    Html.ValidationSummary(true);
    <fieldset>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(itemModel => Model.Rating)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.EditorFor(itemModel => Model.Rating)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(itemModel => Model.Rating)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(itemModel => Model.Review)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.EditorFor(itemModel => Model.Review)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(itemModel => Model.Review)
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Change" />
        </p>
    </fieldset> 

}
```

Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MovieProject2.Models
{
    public class MovieReview
    {
        public int ReviewID { get; set; }
        public Movie MovieReviewed { get; set; }
        public User Reviewer { get; set; }
        public int Rating { get; set; }
        public string Review { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateReviewed { get; set; }

        public MovieReview() { }
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe you mean from controller to view?

Comment: you haven't provided enough information. Possibly haven't investigated. for example `MovieReview review = MovieADO.getReviewByID(id);` does this statement return rows? Is the action method even getting an id passed? or is it using the default -1 (i see problem there)

Comment: No, it passes from the [HttpGet] Edit method in the controller to Edit.cshtml without any trouble, but the review parameter in the [HttpPost] Edit method comes back null when I click submit.

Comment: Dave A: Thank you for noticing.  The action method is getting an id passed.  getReviewsByID(id) then takes the id, queries the database, and sets the values for the MovieReview object.

Comment: So, if you set a breakpoint in the [HttpPost] action - the `review` variable itself is null?  Or are you saying some of it's properties are null?

Comment: The review variable itself is null.

Comment: There is nothing obviously wrong with your code that would cause that to happen.  One thing I note is that you don't have `@Html.HiddenFor( itemModel => Model.ReviewId)` which would be customary for an `Edit` view - but this wouldn't cause your issue.  You don't have anything else in your view do you?

Comment: I went ahead and added in @Html.HiddenFor( itemModel => Model.ReviewId).  The only other thing in my view is commented-out code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(MovieReview review)
```

write

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(MovieReview model)
```

(and rename it further in that method from *review* to *model*. It should work.

OR

rename property of MovieReview.Review to something else (for example, Review1). You cannot have the same name for a property and passed model object (case insensitive)

Comment: Show sources for these claims please.

Comment: @CodeCaster If you create form in a way that user2206127 did, you will find that form elements have names "Rating" and "Review" (without any prefix). When form is posted, it goes through ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValue method (download source for ASP.NET MVC in order to see this), and it will recognize/match "Review" value as "review" (name of action parameter) and pass string as model object...which, of course, cannot be cast into MovieReview object and thus value is null. We can go a bit further in analyzing asp.net mvc source, but this comment box is limited in # of characters.

Comment: I think it's got more to do with OP's 'EditorFor(itemModel => Model' notation. Shouldn't 'Model' be 'itemModel'?

Comment: @CodeCaster you can try that. In my test, I'm still getting null even with "itemModel", but it might happen that there is something else wrong in my test. Anyway, I'm sure that there must be other ways to solve this (including changing source for asp.net mvc). Please, let us know what are your findings.

Answer (score 0):

You have to try this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action methodName","controllerName"))
```

Comment: When I type in @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Reviews")) it still comes back null.  Idk if I did it right.